# add linux swap partition without harming existing data on the hard drive

Tags: partitioning, swap, resize

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 using a bootable USB and followed the instructions. I noticed after installation that I only have a 2GB swapfile which is mounted under root directory(/). I want to separately have a linux swap partition in my hard drive. What is the best possible way to repartition the drive so that I don't loose any information on my existing drive. linux swap of 64GB is optimal for me since my ram is also 64GB.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks

Comment: So system will automatically increase the size if need be?

Comment: @Rinzwind one reason to have a swap partition the size of RAM is for hibernation. Not sure if OP is aware of this need, though: does not appear from the question.

Comment: I followed this link here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-change-swap-size-on-ubuntu-14-04 and managed to change my swapfile size from 2G to 16G. I am still reading about hibernation and whether it is already enabled on my desktop system.

Comment: @Rinzwind **WHAT?** Using a /swapfile will **NOT** *" the system will enlarge it to whatever the max is it needs"*. Where did you hear that?

Comment: @user3138373 How/why did you determine that you need a 64G swap partition?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to remove `Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks` (unneeded text), and replace `loose` with `lose`.

Answer (score 0):

First note that you only want to create a separate swap partition of 64 GB if you intend to enable hibernation. There is no other good reason to have a swap partition 1) that large and 2) on a dedicated swap partition for a desktop computer.

Secondly, note that there is no "best possible way" to repartition a drive. The possibilities depend on the current partitioning layout.

Creating a swap partition will require you to free space on the drive. You effectively can reduce the size of a partition while preserving the data on the partition, provided the existing data still fits on the reduced partition.

So yes, you can add linux swap partition without harming existing data on the hard drive, provides some conditions are met.

There is one single condition: you need to have a current backup of your (personal) data (only that). That the repartitioning does not harm existing data does not excuse you not to have a backup. Even if a procedure in principle preserves your data, things can o wrong, due to human error (you), or software or hardware error.